# Kubernetes pods can ping external IPs but not any domain

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

I have a Kubernetes cluster using the Antrea CNI.

The problem is that I can't `curl` any domain names.

I can do `nslookup` inside the pod and get the IP of any domain, but I can't directly curl the domain.

For example, I can't curl `https://google.com` but I can curl `https://1.1.1.1`

Am I missing something, or is it normal? What do I need to do in order to fix this?

Here is the pod's container's `ip route show table all`

```
default via 10.42.4.1 dev eth0 
10.42.4.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 10.42.4.26 
broadcast 10.42.4.0 dev eth0 table local scope link  src 10.42.4.26 
local 10.42.4.26 dev eth0 table local scope host  src 10.42.4.26 
broadcast 10.42.4.255 dev eth0 table local scope link  src 10.42.4.26 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local scope host  src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local scope link  src 127.0.0.1 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  metric 256 
local ::1 dev lo table local  metric 0 
local fe80::e08c:e8ff:fef3:4877 dev eth0 table local  metric 0 
multicast ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local  metric 256
```

My cluster's cidr is 10.42.0.0/16

Comment: Turns out restarting the `coredns` deployment fixed the issue. It was a bad coredns pod, which is now gladly fixed! Restarting things really does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting comment as the community wiki answer for better visibility:

> Turns out restarting the coredns deployment **fixed the issue**. It was a bad coredns pod, which is now gladly fixed! Restarting things really does work.

Comment: Hello @tymur999. Consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue.